# How to highlist cell A1 if ANY cell in column B is highlighted

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm hoping there's an easy answer using conditional formatting, but if not I'm fine with entering in some VBA.

Column `A` (starting at row 2) has a calculated position (an integer) based on certain criteria.
Column `B` (starting at row 2) has a hard-coded position (an integer).

I have conditional formatting on Column `B` that will highlight the cell red (the "Bad" style format) if the value in `B` is less than the value in `A`. This works great. But I have many of these files and many rows in each file, so I don't want to have to scroll down each file to find a red highlighted cell. What I'd like instead is to highlight cell `A1` if ANY of the cells in Column `B` are highlighted, i.e. are less than their respective `A` cell.

Is this possible with a conditional format in cell `A1`? I've tried `COUNTIFS()` but wasn't able to figure it out, don't know if that's the correct function I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any cell in column **B** is less than the equivalent cell in column **A** then:

```
=MAX(A2:A9999-B2:B9999)>0
```

will be `True`

So you can use the formula in the conditional formatting.

**EDIT#1:**

Enter as an array formula.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Getting an error with this one. Even created a new blank file with just A2-A7 and B2-B7 with dummy data (all ints). Pasted your forumla into A1 and get a `#VALUE!` error

Comment: @amallard  Got it ! ...................this must be an array formula.

Comment: @amallard  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Never knew about array formulas. Works perfect!

Comment: @amallard  Sorry about the stumble.